# How to apply dynamic CSS for the label in IE7

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css, internet-explorer

i am having a server control (Asp:Label) and i want to apply the css class dynamically

but it is applying to the label in all browsers except in IE7

in all browsers the dynamic css classes are applying but in IE7 it is not applying

can u give any solution or any alternate solution

Thanks and Regards,
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: "((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPrice")).Attributes.Add("class", "liforrent");"

I want to apply this class "liforrent" to the label dynamically because the label will contains different colors like red,blue, green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the html is rendered in IE7, does it properly show

```
<span class="liforrent" id="lblPrice"></span>
```

or something similar?

If so, what does your css look like? Are you using something like css hacks which can get misinterpreted by IE7?

Edit: I suggest you download and install [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) to see what styles are put over the span tag in IE7 and resolve it that way.

Comment: <span id="lblPrice" class="liforrent">$0.00</span> and it is not showing the label only in IE7 and in remaining all browsers it is showing the color.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i have the internet explorer developer toolbar and with that i am unable to resolve the issue
as in the aspx.cs file i am adding the attributes dynamically because for different scenarios i used to have different colors so how is it possible to have different colors programatically in ie7. in only ie7 i am having this type of issue in remaining all browsers it is working fine.

Thanks in advance and waiting the reply as soon as possible

Comment: This has probably little to do with ASP.NET itself since that runs on the server. The problem you're seeing lives on the client side (the browser). That's why I proposed you install that toolbar to see what CSS overrides might affect in IE7 the correct working/look & feel of your span tag.